# PowerShell - Problems at using match if the text I need is before the keyword

Tags: regex, powershell, match

My problem is that if I write `$var -match "(id="".*?$args)"`, I get everything from the first `id` of the text to `$args`, but I only need text starting from the `id` which is closest to `$args`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `$var -match "(\bid=""(?:(?!\bid="").)*$args)"`

Comment: can you provide a sample string of `$var` and the expected result?

Comment: [sample string](https://regex101.com/r/gB2yR4/1)
The expected result is the name of the album in which the song title in $args can be found. I solved it by using `-match"(?s)d=(.(?!d=))+$args"` then `$matches[0]-match">""(.*)""<"`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$var` has no properties we can grab, if so just use `select`/`where`, otherwise what you can try is finding the start index of `$args`, then if the IDs are the same length each time you could grab X number of characters before $args.

```
#So it would look something like: ID=xxxxxx$args
$argsIndex = $var.IndexOf($args)

#Lets say the ID is always 6 chars long, grab 6 characters prior using the substring method:    
$var.substring($argsIndex-6,6)
```